# Change value of double in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm having a problem with my code for school I'm trying to modify the double"original_amount" so that the while loop could update the information and print it again and again

It should print this from threshold is $1,000, the smaller interest rate is 0.9%, the larger interest rate is 1.5%, you invest $990, and you want to trace this amount for 3 years

```
Report on John Johnson's saving account:
Original amount              990.00

Year 1:
effective interest rate        0.9%
amount gained                  8.91
amount at the end of Year    998.91

Year 2:
effective interest rate        0.9%
amount gained                  8.99
amount at the end of Year   1007.90

Year 3:
effective interest rate        1.5%
amount gained                 15.12
amount at the end of Year   1023.02

Thanks for using our bank!
```

This is my code:

```
  {
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your name");
String name=input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter your bank's threshold");
int threshold=input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the smaller interest");
double small_interest=input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter tht larger interest");
double large_interest=input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?");
original_amount=input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("How many years do you want the program to trace?");
int trace=input.nextInt();
double effective_interest=0;
if (original_amount>=threshold){
effective_interest=(large_interest);}
else if (original_amount<threshold){
effective_interest=(small_interest);}
double amount_gained=((original_amount * (effective_interest/100)));
double yearly_amount=original_amount+amount_gained;
    int x=1;
    int year=1;
    System.out.println("Report on "+name+"'s savings account :");
    System.out.println("Original Amount "+ original_amount);
     System.out.println("");
     while (x<=trace)
    {
      System.out.println("Year"+year+":");
      System.out.println("Effective interest rate "+effective_interest+"%");
      System.out.println("Amount gained "+amount_gained);
      System.out.println("Amount at the end of the year "+(yearly_amount));
      System.out.println("");
      x++;
      year++;
    }
    original_amount+=amount_gained;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each iteration of the loop you should to do calculations you need to update the information. right now you are only printing, only the variable year is updated. try to put some of the calculations inside the while loop.

**update**
original_amount+=amount_gained; is not inside the while loop. try put it there.

```
while (x<=trace)
    {
      System.out.println("Year"+year+":");
      System.out.println("Effective interest rate "+effective_interest+"%");
      System.out.println("Amount gained "+amount_gained);
      System.out.println("Amount at the end of the year "+(yearly_amount));
      System.out.println("");
      original_amount+=amount_gained;
      x++;
      year++;
    }
```

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, when i put "original_amount+=amount_gained;" inside the while loop nothing happens

Comment: Thats what i tried before it just prints the same thing 3 times instead of updating the original_amount

Comment: you are not printing original_amount you are printing amount_gained. and amount_gained in your code isn't updated.

Comment: Now i got it i set up the while loop to start before all the equations and that worked thanks for that

Comment: Now could you help me fix the printing it prints 8.910000000000002 for the amount_gained, How would i go about making it print just 8.91?

Comment: Math.ceil(double d) and Math.floor(double d) for example. just search and you can find it.

Answer (score 1):

also wanted to point out that having both x and year is unnecessary since they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Didn't really notice it but i guess thats true using both is unnecesssary